# Advice on migrating from a hard disk to SSD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, symbolic-link

I have a Toshiba P50 laptop that is still performing OK for me, despite being 7-years old.  The only gripes I have are:

- it is taking longer to boot (I have a *lot* of stuff installed)
- the 1TB disk is nearly full.

I figure I could kill both these birds by replacing the drive with a 500G SSD, and moving the 1TB (or possibly a new 2 TB) drive to the no-longer-used CD bay as D:.  I would then clone the old 1Tb drive to the SSD, but only \Windows, \Program files*, the remainder can reside on D:

However, I have lots of tools, scripts, installed programs, that expect stuff to be on C:.  Reinstalling it would be a huge task, so my question:

- is it feasible to set up a series of symbolic links on C: to point the folders to D:? Specifically I'm concerned there might be a performance hit, and also that the mapping might not get done early enough for startup routines to find the right data folders (or maybe symbolic linking is done in such a way that it is effective from power-on?).

Any experience or advice appreciated.

Comment: My first take is that 7 years is approaching the outside lifespan for a laptop. second, if you were to get a new SSD, just get a 1TB, and image your existing disk over to it. if you then choose to get an additional disk, transition stuff over to it as you have time and inclination, rather than trying to Frankenstein your existing configuration onto new hardware.

Comment: What about the SSD lifetime? Wouldn't it be degraded of all disk transactions were on the SSD? I do lots of *big* compiles.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to replace the SSD by one of 2 TB (after cloning the existing one to it)?

Comment: @harrymc - see my comments in the reply to Frank above.  I was thinking it would be good to remove the SSD from too much disk churn - the machine speed is quite acceptable, but the fast boot of the SSD is appealing.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

1. Install any SSD in your CD-ROM drive bay
2. Setup a sufficiently large swap file on that drive (windows label "D")
3. Delete the swap file on your primary HDD
4. Reboot

Now compare how the speed of your laptop is affected by that (it won'
t start faster.)

If you are satisfied with the performance you might either

a) move some easy to move data from the HDD to the SSD (do not forget regular backups because we know that SSD never die slowly as HDDs often do)

b) Check if the bay for your primary HDD allows for a 2TB drive in 9,5mm heighth such as the Samsung Spinpoint M9T 2TB, if yes, duplicate your primary HDD to your new HDD drive and replace the primary HDD by your 2TB sized duplicated. Acronis True Image and the like from Paragon Software or Makrium should do the job.

c) Duplicate your 1TB drive to a 2TB SSD and replace the 1TB drive

As for your proposed solution, the feasibility seems to depend on the folder location of your storage-consuming files:
The following has been extracted on the 7.3.2021 out of

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_volume_mount_point

[...
**Limitations
Symbolic links do not work at boot, so it's impossible to redirect e.g.:
hiberfil.sys
\Windows
\Windows\system32
\Windows\system32\Config
Windows Installer does not fully support symbolic links. A redirected \Windows\Installer will cause most .msi-based Windows installers to fail with error 2755 and/or error 1632.
Nevertheless, it is possible to redirect:
\Documents and Settings
\ProgramData
\Program Files
\Program Files (x86)
\Users
Creating symbolic links for \Users and \ProgramData pointing to another drive is not recommended as it breaks updates and Windows Store Apps.[16]
Creating symbolic links for \Users, \ProgramData, "\Program Files" or "\Program Files (x86)" pointing to other locations breaks installation resp. upgrade of Windows.[17]
Creating symbolic links for "\Program Files" or "\Program Files (x86)" pointing to another drive breaks Windows' Component Based Servicing which hardlinks files from its repository \Windows\WinSxS to their installation directory.**
...]

Comment: I don't believe those limitations with the symbolic links would affect me, as the folders I would want to redirect are not OS-related. As an example, I have `c:\admin` and `c:\projects`.  I would set up links `C:\admin --> D:\admin` and `c:\projects --> d:\projects`